# Plural possessive of the acronym COA

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe, acronyms

How do I write the plural possessive of the acronym COA in APA style (which in general doesn't allow for the use of an apostrophe)?

COA = children orphaned by AIDS

Children orphaned by AIDS [acquired immunodeficiency syndrome] sounds like it ends with an 's', but it actually ends with an 'e' (for 'syndrome').

So do I write: 
COA experiences,
COAs experiences, or 
COAs' experiences

Which is the correct answer?

Comment: The first or the last. Not the second. That said, I am finding the very acronym disgusting, denigrating, and dehumanizing. I would never refer to a human child as a COA. *Especially* not if said child lost its parents to AIDS.

Comment: @Reg Happily, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COA) doesn't list it among its 29 expansions. And neither does [the Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/COA) among its c140 (though it _does_ have 'Child of Alcoholic').

Comment: Is it an acronym, or are the letters enunciated separately?

Comment: I guess it's more of an initialism, than an acronym, and must be pronounced/read letter-by-letter: C O A

Comment: @RegDwigfht: It appears that, despite your reaction, the term is used in authorative documents. This is a small sample: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27655351
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4016624/
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0143034314535617
and 
Gender, AIDS and Food Security: Culture and Vulnerability in Rural Côte D'Ivoireb By Mariame Maiga

Comment: The possessive of **children** is **children's** so IMO the possessive of **COA** would be **COA's** not **COAs'**.

Comment: In a document of over 400 pages, it could be quite repetitive and tedious to constantly use the full term 'children orphaned by AIDS'; hence the use of the abbreviation.

Comment: You can get around it with "The experiences of COA / COAs".

Comment: Would the following then work:

...AIDS orphans' experiences and perceptions of ... 

I am just wondering, once you have introduced an acronym/abbreviation, aren't you suppose to only use the abbreviation thereafter (instead of the full term)? 

The problem only comes in when I need to make use of the plural possessive (refer to orphans' experiences/COA experiences).

Otherwise, for the most part, COA works fine in the document.

Comment: There's a problem with referring to a single such unfortunate child. Is COA an invariant plural (ie can COA also mean 'child orphaned by AIDS')? The more normal approach would be to use CXY and CXYs.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response, that makes a lot of sense. (In my specific case, it is used to refer to a selected sample of AIDS orphaned 'children' in a particular region).